# A command in $PATH but can't run and "ln" link not work on Debian 12

Tags: debian, path, latex, ln

The computer system is Debian 12. As needed to update my LaTeX, I tried the command `sudo tlmgr update --all`, which returned `sudo: tlmgr: command not found`. But `which tlmgr` returned `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`, so `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all` worked. However, the `sudo echo $PATH` returned

```
/home/usr1/.local/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

which contains `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:`, so I don't understand why `sudo tlmgr update --all` returned `sudo: tlmgr: command not found`.

I created a symbolic links by `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr /usr/bin/tlmgr`, but `sudo tlmgr update --all` returned

```
"wndws" is not exported by the TeXLive::TLUtils module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 100.
```

And I checked it with `ls -l /usr/bin/tlmgr1`, which returned `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Nov  2 11:30 /usr/bin/tlmgr -> /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`. It seem right.

Why should I add `tlmgr` to `/usr/bin/` and why doesn't  `sudo tlmgr update --all` work?

Comment: @muru Why this one is hard link? I tried `ln -s usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr /usr/bin/tlmgr`, not `ls -l /usr/bin/tlmgr` produces right location. But `sudo tlmgr update --all` produces `"wndws" is not exported by the TeXLive::TLUtils module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 100.`

Comment: Okay. But it seems soft link can't solve this problem. @muru

Comment: @muru Yes. I did as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: If I see this correct, you only checked the `PATH` of your own user (`echo $PATH`), and not of the *root* user (`sudo echo $PATH`)

Comment: @Panki `sudo echo $PATH` produces `/home/usr1/.local/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`. I have modified the question.

Comment: With `sudo echo $PATH`, the `$PATH` is expanded by the shell **before** the command begins executing and `sudo` takes effect, so all you get that way is your own user $PATH echoed to the screen with full force of root. Try `sudo printenv PATH` instead.

Comment: @telcoM Yes. `sudo ptintenv PATH` produces `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. But why the `tlmgr` in `/usr/bin/` doesn't work like the file it links?

Comment: @telcoM thanks for fixing my brainfart.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr` looks at (in shell terms) $0 to figure out where your LaTeX installation lives. When started with the full path, it has no trouble figuring out that the rest of the installation is at `/usr/local/texlive/2023/` and finding the correct versions of all the components it needs.

But with your symlink, this breaks down: either it doesn't find what it needs at all, or if you have Debian 12's standard packaged version of LaTeX installed too, it might search under `/usr`, find `/usr/share/texlive` and then try to use `/usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm` instead of `/usr/local/texlive/2023/[...something...]/TLUtils.pm` which apparently would have more features than Debian's standard version.

And as you can see:

```
grep wndws /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm
```

produces no results, so it clearly doesn't have the `wndws` thing `tlmgr` is trying to import.

In general, unless you are making your own `*.deb` packages, you should not put things into `/usr/bin/` unless you absolutely have to. Instead, use `/usr/local/bin`.

And in this specific case, since `tlmgr` seems to be sensitive to the path used to start it, you should use a simple wrapper script instead of a symbolic link. So create `/usr/local/bin/tlmgr` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr "$@"
```

and then make it executable with `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/tlmgr`.

(The `exec` at the beginning avoids cluttering up the process list with one extra shell process, and `"$@"` causes any parameters given to the script to be passed on to the real `tlmgr` with no changes.)

Comment: What is the difference between `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/local/bin`? Indeed, there is Debian 12's standard packaged version of LaTeX installed automatically, but how can I permanently delete it? As the symlink is created by me, why it will be changed to link to the Debian 12's standard packaged version of LaTeX. If so, the soft link is very unstable.

Comment: `/usr/bin` is controlled by the package manager: it will assume it has permission to overwrite anything in there as it's installing package updates. So if you do any customizations in there, they will be overwritten as soon as there is an update to the standard version of whatever you customized. `/usr/local/bin` is designated for local system-wide customizations: it is in $PATH before `/usr/bin` exactly so that you can place stuff there to be used instead of distribution's standard versions of commands.See: [the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml).

Comment: But, stlil, why the symlink would be changed to point the wrong version of LaTeX. When it runs, it doesn't run the `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`.

Comment: If do this `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr /usr/local/bin/tlmgr`, `sudo tlmgr update --all` will cause `Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC (you may need to install the TeXLive::TLConfig module)`. It seem soft link always doesn't work right.

Comment: The `tlmgr` senses where it's been started from, and will assume that the rest of the same installation of LaTeX is nearby. But the symlink will throw off this assumption: when the symlink is in `/usr/bin/` it will look for `/usr/share` and find the old version of LaTeX; if in `/usr/local/bin`, it will look for `/usr/local/share` and find nothing. **Symlinking `tlmgr` does not work. Use a wrapper script that contains a full path to the real `tlmgr` instead.**

Comment: When does symlink sense and when does it not? Why are symlink in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` relocated to `/usr/local/share`, but other location wouldn't?

Comment: Symlink does not sense anything. When `tlmgr` starts up, it asks the operating system "Where is the binary that was used to start me?". But for the operating system, a symbolic link is as good an answer as the actual file, so with the symlink, the OS will answer "you were started from /usr/bin/tlmgr" (or /usr/local/bin/tlmgr respectively). Then `tlmgr` will go up one or more directories from there and look for other components of LaTeX. If the real path was used, it will eventually find `/usr/local/texlive/2023` and everything it needs will be there; if symlink, it will look in wrong place.

Comment: When start from `/usr/bin/tlmgr` or `/usr/local/bin/tlmgr`, the `tlmgr` should run the file that symlink points. So, why does `tlmgr` find the wrong place?

Comment: Because `tlmgr` asks from the OS "what is the pathname used to start me?", **not** "what is the `realpath(3)` of the pathname used to start me?". `tlmgr` cannot get the "right" answer because it is not asking the right question.

Comment: What does `realpath(3)` mean? What is the meaning of `pathname`? `tlmgr` executes the file in the `/usr/bin/`, am I right? Then what does it use?

Comment: [`realpath(3)` is a C library function.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) `tlmgr` is a short (unqualified) file name; `/usr/bin/tlmgr` and `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr` are two (absolute) pathnames for it. With your symlink, the same file is at both pathnames, and *both pathnames are equally valid for it for most purposes.* Only `realpath("/usr/bin/tlmgr")` would identify the non-symlink pathname, which would be `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`.

Comment: But I still don't know why symlink do wrong things.